# Stuck on Classical intro to Modern Number Theory page 157?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Could anyone who also owns the book explain why points of degree d, raised to powers of q are in the algebraic set V and why they are distinct? (Lines 7 to 11 on page 157). I've looked at chapter 7 on finite fields for the reasoning like the authors advised but can't see why it's true. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Well, no one without access to the book has any hope of answering this. Could you possibly make your question self-contained?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to phrase it so that it would be self-contained and I don't know how to write any of the symbols either.

Comment: If it helps I'm basically looking for information about the properties of prime divisors on an algebraic set V

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference